laravel livewire 3 | component not auto re-render after perform any action
commerce app in laravel livewire3, cart component data not updating after perform any action like updateQty, removeItem etc.
I want to auto update cart itmes values after perform any action.
Cart.php
class Cart extends Component
{
    public $cartItems = [];

    public $sub_total = 0;

    public function mount(){
       $this->cartItems = CartManagement::getCartItemsFromCookies();
       $this->sub_total = CartManagement::calculateGrandTotal($this->cartItems);
    }

    public function removeItem($slug){
        CartManagement::removeCartItem($slug);
        $data = ['type' => 'success', 'message' => 'Item removed successfully.'];
        $this->dispatch('update-cart',data:$data);
    }

    public function increaseQty($slug){
        CartManagement::incrementQuantityToCartItem($slug);
        $data = ['type' => 'success', 'message' => 'Item quantity increased successfully.'];
        $this->dispatch('update-cart',data:$data);
        $this->dispatch('refreshThis');
    }

    public function decreaseQty($slug){
        CartManagement::decrementQuantityToCartItem($slug);
        $data = ['type' => 'success', 'message' => 'Item decreased decreased successfully.'];
        $this->dispatch('update-cart',data:$data);
    }

    public function clearCart(){
        CartManagement::clearCartItems();
        $data = ['type' => 'success', 'message' => 'All items removed successfully.'];
        $this->dispatch('update-cart',data:$data);
    }

    public function refreshThis() {
        $this->render();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.partials.cart');
    }
}

cart.blade.php
the below code is front end blade view from where i am performing actions.
@foreach ($cartItems as $crt)
    <tr :key="{{ $crt['slug'] }}">
            <td class="border p-2">
                    <img class="h-10 w-10 inline-block" src="{{ env('APP_URL').'storage/'.$crt['image'] }}" alt="{{ $crt['title'] }}">
                    <span>
                            {{ $crt['title'] }}
                    </span>
            </td>
            <td class="border text-center">{{ number_format($crt['unit_amount'],2)  }}</td>
            <td class="border mx-auto">
                    <div class="flex justify-center">
                            <button wire:click="decreaseQty('{{ $crt['slug'] }}')" wire:loading:attr="disabled" class="bg-primary text-white text-xs px-3">-</button>
                            <input type="text" value="{{ $crt['quantity'] }}" class="bg-secondary text-black text-xs border-none text-center w-10" readonly>
                            <button wire:click="increaseQty('{{ $crt['slug'] }}')" wire:loading:attr="disabled" class="bg-primary text-white text-xs px-3">+</button>

                    </div>
            </td>
            <td class="border text-center">{{ number_format($crt['total_amount'],2) }}</td>
            <td class="border text-center">
              <button wire:click="removeItem('{{ $crt['slug'] }}')" wire:loading:attr="disabled" class="bg-primary text-white text-xs px-2 py-1">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
                    Remove
            </button>      
            </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach

Looking forward for help, thanks in advance.

Everytime a call to the backend is done, the render() method is called automatically (if you do not provide it explicitly, a default render is done), so you do not need the refreshThis() method.
The main problem in your code is that you have set the ':key="{{ $crt['slug'] }}"` attribute in the <tr> tag but in Livewire 3 it must be "wire:key":
<tr wire:key="cart-{{ $crt['slug'] }}">

note that I've also added the cart- prefix to avoid conflicts with other wire:key in the same page.
Here the wire:key documentation
Instead, the :key attribute is needed for subcomponents rendered into loops (here you can find the documentation)

as per nested component documentation i created new child component "cart-row" & then itterate in foreach loop this child component <livewire:partials.cart-row :$crt :key="time().$crt['slug']" /> & setup my all actions like updateQty, removeItem etc in child component. but not able to re render my cart component.

You can update your question by adding the new component and how you include it at the bottom - this may help identify the current problem
